# How to get this data name inside object user?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

this my array

```
[{
  user_id: "05472250-fee3-11e9-9d4b-93808060db24",
   user: {
        "id": "05472250-fee3-11e9-9d4b-93808060db24",
        "name": "Telkom Sample User",
        "status": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-11-04T02:11:01.000Z",
        "updated_at": null
      },
}]
```

I have `foreach` the data above and below the code, but in the `{{item.user.name}}` section I get an error, the error **Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**. Is there something wrong in my code?

[image]

Comment: With the given array, I don't see problem, you might have object without user in the results. you need check the array!

Comment: Can you also check the format of your array

Comment: sorry I copied and pasted this array so there are quotes

Comment: i think in the iteration, you need to change the key 
`v-for" item in dataRequest" : key="item.user.id">`